# Iterative query without using CTE (or cursors!)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some data in a table that looks similar to this:

```
Item    Date         Price
A       8/29/2012    $3
B       8/29/2012    $23
C       8/29/2012    $10
A       8/30/2012    $4
B       8/30/2012    $25
C       8/30/2012    $11
A       8/31/2012    $3
B       8/31/2012    $22
C       8/31/2012    $8
A       9/01/2012    $3
B       9/01/2012    $26
C       9/01/2012    $9
A       9/02/2012    $3
B       9/02/2012    $24
C       9/02/2012    $9
```

I need to write a query that identifies that price for A hasn't changed 
since 8/30/2012, price for item C hasn't changed since 9/01/2012, and 
to return the number of days elapsed for both (we're looking for items 
with non-moving prices). I can't use CTE, or cursors, or separately created 
temp tables (select into, etc) because of the limitations of the web report 
tool this sql needs to run in. I can only use a 'basic' single pass select query 
(subqueries will work though). Does anyone have any cunning ideas on how to 
achieve this??

My first attempt was to group by Item and Price, where price is the same as 
the latest price, `having count > 2`, identifying the min date and doing a datediff
between min date and getdate. However this just identifies the first instance of 
that price, it doesn't take into account any subsequent rows that might have a 
different price. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Btw: you can always write a view that will return the needed information and then do a SELECT from that view from within your reporting tool

Comment: Sorry, should have said, this is SQL Server 2008. Sadly I can't write a view either - this is a vendor hosted database and we have read-only rights to it!

Comment: I had some ideas using the `lag()` function (I thought you might be using Oracle or PostgreSQL) but SQL Server 2008 doesn't support that.

Comment: Can you show the example output you'll like?

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for that. I've not come across lag - looks like it's available in SQL 2012.

Comment: Hi Magnus - something like: A $3 3days, C $9 2days. Thanks

Comment: And if the price has changed since 8/30/2012 do not include at all?

Comment: That's correct Magnus. Fundamentally we're just trying to identify stale prices, so we want to ignore any items where the price is changing and identify any items where the price is static and work out how many days it's been static for. Sounds like a really easy query to start with, until you take all the 'programming' options out of the equation and try and make this purely set based.

Comment: BTW, thank you for the responses guys - my first time on here and wasn't sure what to expect :-)

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for the 'last changed date', compared to the 'current' day of `2012-09-02`?  And `B` is excluded because it was changed 'yesterday' (`2012-09-01`)?

Comment: That's correct. Looking for last changed date and then will do a datediff to todays date. The query should ignore B as the price is changing each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given both types of ages and account for items that exist only once in the table (they don't have an old date).  Please let us know how close this is.

UPDATE: I had to correct the date calculation in "PriceAgeToNow", and I've also tried to filter out records that are have only had a new price for 1 day.  Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4633).

```
-- Get the age of the current price
select *
    , datediff(d, c.OldDate, getdate()) as PriceAgeToNow
    , datediff(d, c.OldDate, c.NewDate) as PriceAgeToNewestDate
from (
    select *
        -- Get max date of former price
        , isnull(
            (select max(Date) from PricingTable where Item = b.Item and Date < b.NewDate and Price != b.NewPrice), b.NewDate
        ) as OldDate
    from (
        -- Get current price
        select *
            , (select Price from PricingTable where Item = a.Item and Date = a.NewDate) as NewPrice
        from (
            -- Get current date
            select Item
                , max(Date) as NewDate
            from PricingTable
            group by Item
        ) a
    ) b
) c
-- Attempt to filter out price changes that have only lasted 1 day
where datediff(d, c.OldDate, c.NewDate) > 1
```

Comment: Works, but includes `B` rows (which the OP is excluding because they changed 'yesterday').

Comment: Good call, I didn't see all of the comments yet. It should be easy enough to filter out such records, but I'm having trouble understanding the exact definition for them in the comments.

Comment: That's looking very promising Tim, thank you very much! I'll need a little while to play with it to fit the actual data - will let you know how it goes. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tim - sorry, how does the @pricing declaration work in this?

Comment: Don't worry - I've got it. What platform are you using?

Comment: This is working in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I've added a [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4633).

Comment: Excellent. This works great. I just added "where datediff(d, isnull(c.OldDate, c.NewDate), c.NewDate) > 1" to filter out the B's and it's returning what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome.  Yep, that was one of my last revisions, too.  Vote up / mark as answer for future visitors!

Comment: I think I need some additional 'reputation' thingies to vote up. Will do if/when I reach the magic 15 :-)

Comment: You can reach 15 by marking this as the correct answer, if, in fact, it is.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*** Updated [with fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed891/3): ***

Will this work?

```
SELECT ct.Item,
    ct.Price,
    datediff(day, max(yt.[Date]), ct.[Date]) AS ChangeDays
FROM
    (SELECT Item, max(Date) as LastDate FROM YourTable GROUP BY Item) maxdata
    INNER JOIN YourTable ct on ct.Item = maxdata.Item and ct.[Date] = maxdata.LastDate
    INNER JOIN YourTable yt on yt.Item = ct.Item and yt.[Date] < ct.[Date] and yt.Price <> ct.Price
GROUP BY ct.Item, ct.Price, ct.[Date]
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! Playing with this now too. Very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a preference for using windows functions where they are most appropriate.  And, in this case, there is an interesting trick for finding sequences of things that are the same.  Enumerate them (with row_number) over all the data, partitioned by item and ordered by date.  And then enumerate them, over all the data, partitioned by item and price and ordered by date.

For A, you would get

```
A 8/29 $3 1 1
A 8/30 $4 2 1
A 8/31 $3 3 2
A 9/1  $3 4 3
A 9/3  $3 5 4
```

The difference between the last two columns is constant, for any sequence of prices that remain constant in the data.  We can then use this to find when that sequence begins.  The following query takes this approach:

```
select item, price, (id_seqnum - ipd_seqnum) as groupid, min(date) as mindate
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by date) id_seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by item, price order by date) as ipd_seqnum,
             max(date) over (partition by item) as maxdate
      from prices p
     ) t
group by item, price, (id_seqnum - ipd_seqnum)
having max(date) = max(maxdate)
```

It also find the maximum date for each item, and then chooses the grouping that has the maximum date.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. That's an interesting alternative - will play with that also. Learning a lot today :-)